# How can I reduce my execution time for this code?

Tags: python

```
import math
class Solution:
    def countSquares(self, N):
        list = []
        count = 0
        for i in range(1,(int)(math.sqrt(N))):
            square = i ** 2
            list.append(square)
            count = count + 1
        return count
```

I am trying to count the number of perfect squares that are less than a given 'N'.
For example, if N = 9, the output is 2. Because only 1 & 4 are the perfect squares present.

Comment: I tried editing this part:

    `M = int(math.sqrt(N))`
    `for i in range(1,M):`

So that it does not perform the math operation in loops again and again. But still, this does not work. I need to get it done in 1.06 seconds.

Comment: Expect a solution that does not use a loop should be possible.  If `N` is  a perfect square, it would return `math.sqrt(N) - 1` else just `(int)math.sqrt(N)`

Comment: Minor improvement - You don't need a count variable when you can take the length of the list. Alternatively, you're only counting, so the list is pointless

Comment: let me guess... you have always used C++, right? What are you doing with (int)? Is it like a c++ casting?

Comment: @SahilKarnany `for i in range(1,(int)(math.sqrt(N)))` only performs the square root once.

Comment: @khelwood I need it to do only once right? I need to square the numbers more than once

Comment: @SahilKarnany I mean that `M = int(math.sqrt(N))` `for i in range(1,M):` is no different from `range(1,(int)(math.sqrt(N)))`.

Comment: You only seem to need the count, not the list. And the count is the number of iterations your loop goes through. So you don't need to perform the loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```py
math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) - 1
```

`math.sqrt` will output the square root of the current number.

`math.ceil` converts that number into the next whole number.

`- 1` gives you the previous whole number, which is also the (inclusive) count of whole numbers which can be squared to a number less than `n`.

If you need to get the list of the square roots instead of the count the modifications are simple.

```py
list(range(1, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))))
```

In this case `- 1` doesn't need to be performed so `range` ends with the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list(map(lambda x:x*x, range(1,1+int(math.sqrt(n-1)))))
```

Comment: OP wants the amount, not the actual list

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for i in range(1, X):
   #... 
   count = count + 1
```

ends with `count == X - 1`. Therefore, you don't really need a loop. You also never actually use the list, so storing it will slow down the program further.

```
sq = math.sqrt(N)
if math.floor(sq) < sq <= math.ceil(sq):
    return int(sq)
return int(sq) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import math

class Solution:
    def countSquares(self, N):
        n = math.floor(math.sqrt(N))
        if n * n == N:
            return n - 1
        else:
            return n
```